# Getting the last n period high and low for a vector

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the best way to get the higgest value from a list/numpy/vector/pandas column for a given time frame in Python?

I have a pandas dataframe and for one of the columns I want to put a new column with the max value of the past 3 values (or for a given past time frame).

For instance I want to build this dataframe starting with only the timestamp and value1 column:

```
timestamp   value1  max3    min3
10:00:00    8       NA      NA
10:00:05    2       NA      NA
10:00:10    5       NA      NA
10:00:15    7       8       2
10:00:20    10      7       2
```

I could easily do this with a for cycle, but it would be highly inefficient. So, any faster alternative?

Comment: Those slashes make this a bunch of separate questions; the best way to do it for pandas data frame will not work on a list, and the best way to do it with a list will be much slower on a pandas data frame. So… which one are you actually asking?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a `rolling_max` and `rolling_min` combined with a `shift` since you don't want to include the current value in the calculation:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                     value1
timestamp                  
2014-01-10 10:00:00       8
2014-01-10 10:00:05       2
2014-01-10 10:00:10       5
2014-01-10 10:00:15       7
2014-01-10 10:00:20      10

[5 rows x 1 columns]

In [18]: df['max3'] = pd.rolling_max(df['value1'], window=3).shift()

In [19]: df['min3'] = pd.rolling_min(df['value1'], window=3).shift()

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
                     value1  max3  min3
timestamp                              
2014-01-10 10:00:00       8   NaN   NaN
2014-01-10 10:00:05       2   NaN   NaN
2014-01-10 10:00:10       5   NaN   NaN
2014-01-10 10:00:15       7     8     2
2014-01-10 10:00:20      10     7     2

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```